# How to read sound card DMA buffer using API?

Tags: windows, audio

Is it possible to read the sound card DMA buffer using API in windows XP and vista?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to write a driver to get at the actual DMA buffer.

If you're trying to get timely input from the microphone (e.g., for speech recognition), then you might be able to use Windows [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).